# Issues while Fetching API data in my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a json file:

```
{"area":[{"id":"1","name":"abc","address":"223 "},{"id":"2","name":"xyz","address":"123 "}]
```

How to pull the data using react and redux in my component?

I have loaded the url using redux, I am able to see the data in my console but not on UI page.

Actions.js

```
const apiURL = 'my/api/goes/here';

export const fetchUsers = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get(apiURL)
    .then(dispatch(fetchUsersBegin()))
    .then(resp =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(resp.data));
      }, 1000)
    )
    .catch(err => dispatch(fetchUsersFailure()));
};
```

Component.js

```
render() {
    const { error, loading, items } = this.props;
    console.log(items);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Result</h1>
        {items.area}
        {Object.keys(items).map(arr => {
          return (
            <div>
              Id is : {arr[1].id} 
            </div>
          )`
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share that part of the code how you pull the data from the API and the additional `render` function what you have for your component? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the `render` function the data is shown, represented in `console.log()`. I guess the issue is your are trying to map an array which returns `['area']` only.

See the result below:

```js
const items = {
  "area": [{
      "id":"1","name":"abc","address":"223 "
    }, {
      "id":"2","name":"xyz","address":"123 "
    }
  ]
};

console.log(Object.keys(items));
```

Instead try to do `map()` on `items.area` where each item contains the `id` as follows:

```
{
   items && items.area.map(e => {
       return (
          <div>
             Id is : {e.id}
          </div>
       )
   })
}
```

**Explanation:**

So technically you are calling `map()` on the `items.area` array which gives you each element while you are iterating through the array. By doing that you can get the necessary properties in return.

`items &&` is used to check if `items` is containing value, if it does, it maps the `items.area` array in your `render` function.

Read further here: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

I hope this helps!

Comment: It is working if I store the data in my component state. But when I am directly calling it from my api, it says map is not a function. Is there any other way to pull the data?

Comment: @PraisyM Usually that error happens when you have in the variable what you call `map()` on something else than an array. This happened here as well, because `{ area: [] }` is an object. Object does not have function called `map()`. You need to access `items.area` which is an array so you can call `map()` on. I hope that clarifies.